# Webscraping BeautifulSoup object not extractable due to formatting problem

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to extract information from a website, however I can not access the information I want to because the html-code is formatted in a way that doesn't allow me to access the information.
In the html Code below, I would like to extract the mtl. You can see that the after the class=, the '3D "closes" before the whole class name is finished. I tried every possible version to access the mtl., but its not possible.

```
<div class='3D"ServiceOffer_badge__kriSF"'>
  <div>
   <p ce__offering___1cjqq="" class='3D"Pri=' inline;"="" price__brand___2kedu="" price__large="___35JMV" price__price___38oh2="" price__price___38oh2"="" style='3D"display:'>
    <span class='3D"Pr=' ice__value___wawnq"="">
     0 =E2=82=AC
    </span>
    <span class='3D"Price__suffix___1=' d8-m"="">
     mtl.
    </span>
```

Do you have any idea how to do this?
Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


html = '''<div class='3D"ServiceOffer_badge__kriSF"'>
  <div>
   <p ce__offering___1cjqq="" class='3D"Pri=' inline;"="" price__brand___2kedu="" price__large="___35JMV" price__price___38oh2="" price__price___38oh2"="" style='3D"display:'>
    <span class='3D"Pr=' ice__value___wawnq"="">
     0 =E2=82=AC
    </span>
    <span class='3D"Price__suffix___1=' d8-m"="">
     mtl.
    </span>'''
    
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
spanStr = soup.find('span', {'class':'3D"Price__suffix___1='}).text.strip()
```

**Output:**

```
print(spanStr)
mtl.
```